# How can some HTML code be isolated from the rest of the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to allow the user to customize their user name using HTML tags, without restrictions.
The only problem I've found is they not closing tags...

Ex: (a user name with not closed tag: `my<b>nick`)

> my**nick: comment text**
> **innocent user: comment text**

I searched for a tag like `<sandbox> my <b>nick </sandbox>` or any way to force closing every open tag, but I have not been lucky.

Desired result:

> my**nick**: comment text
> innocent user: comment text

Is there any smart way to achieve this? (Only using HTML or JS/JQuery)

Comment: This will drive you mad. You need to either get your users to format their HTLM correctly of severely limit their use of it (i.e. use a HTML editor not allow users to enter their own HTML). There is no magic bullet for this problem.

Comment: Maybe you could use some markdown library ..? That would be safer, and also takes care about correctness of the final HTML.

Comment: Short of parsing it yourself and applying the correct rules around which tags are self closing / have content etc, this isn't really doable properly.  And if you're allowing users to enter pretty much anything and have it displayed to other people, you're opening yourself up directly to scripting injections

Comment: when you allow user to type their name e.g: `Bill<b>gates`, how are you storing it in backend? using PHP-mySQL?

Comment: Backend uses Python-SQL server.

Thanks for the quick replies. It seemed a trivial problem at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any incomplete tags, the browser automatically tries to close it(*doesn't seem to happen if you have an HTML code following*).
If you look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hwpLyow0/1/

I have the HTML inside the DIV as
`Hello <b><i>World!`

But when I alert the HTML from the DIV I get
`Hello <b><i>World!</i></b>`

I would suggest using jQuery's `.html()` function or JavaScript's `.innerHTML` to get the HTML with tags closed.

**EDIT:**

If users are typing it in textbox, creating a new element(*not appending it to document*) will do the work for you.

```
var fix = document.createElement("div");
fix.innerHTML=document.getElementById("test").value;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hwpLyow0/3/